# Understanding the Limitations of Live Server with Vue Applications

Tags: html, visual-studio, vue.js, amazon-s3, static

First, let's imagine there is a very simple HTML that prints 'Hello World'. This can be viewed in a web browser using the VS Extension called Live Server. Similarly, if uploaded to S3, you can also view the HTML. Essentially, they perform the same function, right?

Now, to get to the main point.

I created and built a Vue project. This process generates an 'index.html' along with CSS and JS files in a folder named 'dist'. However, I noticed that I can't run this 'index.html' using Live Server, but I can view it when it's uploaded to S3.

So, what I want to ask is:

1. Is the inability of VS Studio's Live Server to display the built index.html of a Vue application just a limitation of Live Server?
2. And, the Vue page I created shows a graph tracking the number of clicks on a shortened URL. Is this considered a static page?

I'm a bit confused about what I'm misunderstanding here... I'd appreciate a detailed explanation.

I tried to run the 'index.html' file inside the 'dist' folder created after building a Vue application with Live Server, but nothing showed up. So, I just uploaded it to AWS S3, and then I was able to view it.

Comment: If the app uses absolute links like <script src="/dist/whatever.js"> and you serve the page like localhost:12345/dist/index.html, the resources will fail to load, this would be the first concern when serving a simple app that doesn't use a router. 1. probably yes, but it's unknown what's your case, how you build the app and how you configured the extension, the question doesn't make sense without this info. 2. it's unknown what's your case, what you mean by "static page", and why "static" matters

Comment: Browsers trust remote servers more than local files. I would suspect the .js is not being executed when running the .html file directly.